# Put form and list in the same page on backend

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

Is it possible to put form and list in the same page on octobercms backend..? since the form is too short and many area left empty..  thats why i have this in mind..

fields.yaml only contain three fields..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not But for that you need to `render list and form manually`, as `controller is already having list and form behavior most of time` if you use `builder` and `create controller` with `form and list`.

but if you want `all thing manually from beginning`, I have **first class tutorial** for you, after watching it you can `easily add multiple list` and `forms` in single `controller` :)

please check out this tutorial : https://vimeo.com/200392776
 and same on YouTube :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVqc9U6OuLI&t=493s
[Rendering form and list by hand]

please comment if you find still issue creating forms and list I can explain more about them.

Comment: i am sorry to tell you but vimeo is block in indonesia.. do you have other site.. youtube maybe?

Comment: Yes let me share you that link

Comment: Updated answers added YouTube link please use that one

Comment: Great one sir.. though i have watch more than 5 times.. to get the point..  working on my idea.. will come back again when i am stuck..

Comment: sure you can ask anytime